# Как узнать ip домена?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, ip

Можно ли с помощью `requests` в рамках одного запроса к домену узнать ip на котором он расположен?

Условно:

```py
import requests
r = request.get('https://google.com/')
```

Из объекта `r` я могу узнать `ip`?

Comment: Что-то даже в `r.headers` ничего такого не видать. Скорее всего нужно резолвить домен.

Comment: @CrazyElf есть много доменов и надо по мимо запроса к ним еще и их `ip` узнать. Есть какие-то идеи, как это наиболее быстро сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку `socket`

```
import socket

host = 'google.com'

ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(host)

print(ips)
```

Вместо `socket.gethostbyname_ex` можно использовать `socket.getaddrinfo`, если вас интересуют и IPv6-адреса.

Comment: Я читал про этот метод, а как это изнутри работает? Это же тоже запрос куда-то отправляется, на уровне `ping`, полагаю. На сколько сильно это может сказаться на скорости работы при большом кол-ве доменов?

Comment: Ну, по идее такого рода информация может браться только из DNS. Запросы к DNS должны обрабатываться достаточно быстро (уж в любом случае быстрее, чем get запрос через requests, т.к. get-запрос всё равно сначала к DNS обратится). Про точную скорость работы не могу сказать, это зависит от вашего доступа к сети. Попробуйте на какой-то части ваших доменов, и если скорость вас не устроит - попробуйте распараллелить работу.

Comment: Я бы ещё закешировать попробовал такие запросы, если будет много запросов на один и тот же домен.

Comment: @CrazyElf тут уже пора aiodns ставить в таком случае